# CORS Access on Tomcat REST API

Tags: javascript, angularjs, rest, tomcat, cors

I have a local Tomcat installation running on port 8081 exposing a REST API. My development web server is running on port 9000. Now I want to call the REST from javascript code running in the browser using angular's `$http`. This is obviously a CORS call and I had the error:

> "No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested
>   resource. Origin 'http://localhost:9000' is therefore not allowed
>   access."

I added a filter to the Tomcat configuration as proposed by the documentation:

```
<filter>
    <filter-name>CorsFilter</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.apache.catalina.filters.CorsFilter</filter-class>
</filter>
<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>CorsFilter</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
```

This worked perfectly fine for my `GET` requests, but now I want to perform `POST` requests and the error is back again. Why so? Shouldn't that filter allow `POST` as well?

Answer (score 0):

You need to add some [init params](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/config/filter.html#CORS_Filter):

```
<init-param>
  <param-name>cors.allowed.methods</param-name>
  <param-value>GET,POST,HEAD,OPTIONS,PUT</param-value>
</init-param>
<param-value>Content-Type,X-Requested-With,accept,Origin,Access-Control-Request-Method,Access-Control-Request-Headers, Last-Modified</param-value>
```

Comment: Sorry, but it's still not working.I used the advanced configuration example from the documentation link, you provided. This should contain everything necessary, but nothing...